# UniVerse SQL View All Tablenames

Tags: sql, universe

I am new to UniVerse. I am working with an existing Database. I would like to know how to View a List of all available TABLES in the database. Is there a simply syntax command to view all TABLES?

Answer (score 1):

At TCL:

```
LIST VOC WITH F1 = "F]"
```

This will list all file/table entries registered in a specific account (database) on the database server.

If you're looking for all accessible files, including files that may be in other accounts (databases) on the server, use the following query:

```
LIST VOC WITH F1 = "F]" OR F1 = "Q]"
```

Comment: Thank you, truly appreciate your reply! Accepted. It seems I am unable to Vote Up as I only have 1 reputation : (

Comment: On my system this would yeild no results. I am not sure if this is due to convention or flavor. Additionally file can be of Type 'F' or 'Q' and the older the system (or developer) the more likely you are to have 'Q's. I would use " LIST VOC WITH F1 LIKE F... OR F1 LIKE Q... F1"

Answer (score 1):

Type "F" would only return results of physical files in that account.  Type "Q" are Q-Pointers that point to physical files in other accounts.  This is a way to have one file, but several accounts point to that file.

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS SINTAXIS

a)... THIS IS FOR CONTENTS

LIST (NAME OF DATABASE)

b) ... THIS IS FOR DICTIONARY

LIST DICT (NAME OF DATABASE)