# UniVerse SQL List all Fields within a Table

Tags: sql, universe

Within UniVerse, I would like to List all the Tablename Fields and Attributes. In MySQL it may be something similar to $ DESC PRODUCT; I am only getting up to speed with UniVerse. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UniVerse SQL View All Tablenames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944661/universe-sql-view-all-tablenames)

Comment: `LISTF` will tell you the files/tables available ;).

Comment: Thank you! I do appreciate your help, UniVerse does not have much documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the column listing in UniVerse with RetrieVe or SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052734/how-do-i-find-the-column-listing-in-universe-with-retrieve-or-sql)